# New-AzureRmResourceGroup command not working in powershell

Tags: powershell, azure

I have logged into my Azure account and selected the appropriate subscription.
But it always gives the same error

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> New-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name "AzureMediaServicesSample" -Location "East US"
New-AzureRmResourceGroup : Run Login-AzureRmAccount to login.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name "AzureMediaServicesSample" -Location " ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-AzureRmResourceGroup], PSInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperation,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzur
   eResourceGroupCmdlet
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have selected the subscription too using select-azuresubscription

`select-azuresubscription` is used for ASM mode.

For ARM mode, you need use `Get-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionName "your sub" | Select-AzureRmSubscription` to select your subscription.

More information  please refer to this [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azureps-cmdlets-docs/#step-3-run-azure-powershell-cmdlets).

Update:

You could use the following cmdlet to check Azure PowerShell version.

```
Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name Azure -Refresh
```

You could install the latest PowerShell from the [link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/releases).

Comment: Do you have multi subscriptions? If yes, you need select your subscription firstly.

Comment: I have selected the subscription too using select-azuresubscription

Comment: `select-azuresubscription` only works for classic mode. `New-AzureRmResourceGroup` and `New-AzureRmResourceGroup` are ARM cmdlet. You should use cmdlet `Select-AzureRmSubscription`.

Comment: Tried same command after using Select-AzureRmSubscription. Same error

Comment: Could you create group on Azure Portal by using this subscription? You could use `Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name Azure -Refresh` to get your PowerShell version. The latest version is 3.6.0.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138194/discussion-between-walter-msft-and-charu).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it by changing the environment setting from Bash to Powershell in the upper left corner of the Cloud Shell Window.