# How to solve Deploying template using PowerShell script failed error

Tags: .net, azure, azure-sql-database

I am trying to deploy SQL SERVER and DATABASE to azure from visual studio with the azure resource group template.But i am always getting this error:
Deploying template using PowerShell script failed error

The other answers on the stackoverflow were without help.
This is the code in the azuredeploy.json file

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "copydbAdminLogin": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1
    },
    "copydbAdminLoginPassword": {
      "type": "securestring"
    },
    "databasecopyName": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1
    },
    "databasecopyCollation": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1,
      "defaultValue": "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"
    },
    "databasecopyEdition": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "Basic",
      "allowedValues": [
        "Basic",
        "Standard",
        "Premium"
      ]
    },
    "databasecopyRequestedServiceObjectiveName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "Basic",
      "allowedValues": [
        "Basic",
        "S0",
        "S1",
        "S2",
        "P1",
        "P2",
        "P3"
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Describes the performance level for Edition"
      }
    }},
  "variables": {
    "copydbName": "[concat('copydb', uniqueString(resourceGroup().id))]"},
  "resources": [
    {
      "name": "[variables('copydbName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "apiVersion": "2014-04-01-preview",
      "dependsOn": [ ],
      "tags": {
        "displayName": "copydb"
      },
      "properties": {
        "administratorLogin": "[parameters('copydbAdminLogin')]",
        "administratorLoginPassword": "[parameters('copydbAdminLoginPassword')]"
      },
      "resources": [
        {
          "name": "AllowAllWindowsAzureIps",
          "type": "firewallrules",
          "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
          "apiVersion": "2014-04-01-preview",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', variables('copydbName'))]"
          ],
          "properties": {
            "startIpAddress": "0.0.0.0",
            "endIpAddress": "0.0.0.0"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "[parameters('databasecopyName')]",
          "type": "databases",
          "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
          "apiVersion": "2014-04-01-preview",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', variables('copydbName'))]"
          ],
          "tags": {
            "displayName": "databasecopy"
          },
          "properties": {
            "collation": "[parameters('databasecopyCollation')]",
            "edition": "[parameters('databasecopyEdition')]",
            "maxSizeBytes": "1073741824",
            "requestedServiceObjectiveName": "[parameters('databasecopyRequestedServiceObjectiveName')]"
          }
        }
      ]
    }],
  "outputs": {}
}
```

Please help

Comment: whats the exact error text?

Comment: First i get The term 'Get-AzureRmResourceGroup' is not recognized as the  after that Deploying template using PowerShell script failed.

Comment: The bash script is opened and closed after two second i dont get a chance to type in the password that i configured before deployment

Answer (score 0):

As I've seen the issue could be,

you need the AzureRM dependency so you need to run the following command:

**`Install-Module AzureRM`**

Comment: Thanks for your response.I've installed the module through power shell ISE and after that i get the same error....

Comment: can you post what exactly it is

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42827788/new-azurermresourcegroup-command-not-working-in-powershell check if this helps

Comment: I've checked that.Wihout any help